# How to catch exceptions thrown by the service in cloud feign

Tags: spring, microservices, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-feign

When using spring cloud feign, I want to catch exceptions thrown by the service, but all I can get:

```
 nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of ...
```

Comment: Could you share some code snippet and full stack trace?

Comment: Thank youI think it's because feign calls the service over HTTP, and when the service throws an exception directly, the caller can't handle that information while deserializing it.We used @Exceptionhandler to wrap the exception into an APIResult object, and each time the caller had to retrieve the returned data through the APIResult, which was cumbersome, so I wanted the caller to catch the exception thrown by the service provider directly, and normally receive the returned data directly.